# RSA Encryption on iPhone using mod and exp

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to do RSA encryption on iPhone. I have tried many examples found on CryptoUtil and SecKeyWrapper libraries but I always get Null SecKeyRef.

code from this library:
https://github.com/meinside/iphonelib/blob/master/security/CryptoUtil.h

```
NSData *key=[CryptoUtil generateRSAPublicKeyWithModulus:[mod dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] exponent:[exp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        if (key) {
            Boolean status=[CryptoUtil saveRSAPublicKey:key appTag:@"AppIdentifier"  overwrite:YES];
            if (status) {
                SecKeyRef ref=[CryptoUtil loadRSAPublicKeyRefWithAppTag:@"AppIdentifier"];
                return [[CryptoUtil encryptString:pin RSAPublicKey:ref padding:kSecPaddingPKCS1] base64Encoding];
            }


        }
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: I have posted my code.

Comment: I would suggest to directly use the iPhone functions themselves. If you look at the code, that load is a single call to [`SecItemCopyMatching`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemCopyMatching). Note that the `CryptoUtil` class does log errors, so check your log (and post it here).

Comment: Yes, I have debugged the method to get the SecKeyRef and it calls  SecItemCopyMatching and the result was success and on same time SecKeyRef returned was Null.

Comment: Did not fix the issue but i was able to do the RSA encryption using using openssl library.

Comment: @Sarah are you able to detail how you did this?